# Glassfish and Spring Boot: .war re-deployment failed

Tags: spring, glassfish, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy an application build from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war to local glassfish4. And it delpoys well for the first time (if I can call some exceptions from the framework good behaviour). At least, I can open the project's index page in browser.

But if I try to undeploy it and re-deploy, or just overwrite .war file in autodeploy directory, deployment fails. And nothing seems to be added to glassfish log file.

The projects I published from eclipse using some its mechanisms deployed and re-deployed successfully.

Here is the log with related contents:
http://pastebin.com/zSeMw5tC

What can be the problem?

Comment: This looks like someone is having the same problem with JBoss, see [#777](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/777)

Answer (score 2):

I did some experiments with Glassfish a while ago. The CDI implementation is really broken IMO (it shouldn't load classes to scan them for annotations), but the apps I tried worked on GF 4 if there is a `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml` containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd"
bean-discovery-mode="none">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="org.springframework.**" />
        <exclude name="org.apache.**" />
        <exclude name="com.google.**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```

Nothing I did ever worked in GF 3 (older CDI spec and no way to exclude things I think).

Comment: I added the file you provided to WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/ inside the .war, but there is no change, the same exception, same behaviour. But the contents seem to be exactly what I need, taking into account the issue on github that was mentioned. Did I do something wrong? (I can make mistakes in almost anything!)

Comment: I think maybe the version of Glassfish and CDI is very important. I used 4.0 out of the box (I believe judging from the `glassfish-version.properties`).

Comment: Interesting. Even if I execute "asadmin deploy --property implicitCdiEnabled=false x.war" I see the same exceptions. Meaning that either I can't disable that or I'm disabling something wrong.

Comment: It would be useful if that property was respected. I read about it in various places but it never seemed to work for me either (maybe it isn't supported in GF4?).